# Orchard CMS render media public URL for path in theme razor template

Tags: orchardcms

Looking  to add a theme setting for a site logo URL to render in the header. However, when using Azure blob storage for images, the URL is not relative and will need to ask the media library for the public URL.

Just wondering what the best way to do this is from the shape template for my header / branding?

Currently is only working with file system media storage:

```
<a class="logo" href="@Href("~/")">
    <img width="103" height="39" alt="" src="@Href(settings.SiteLogoUrl)" >
</a>
```

Prefer to sore only a relative path in the setting so that any changes to public URL of the Auzre blob storage wont break the site.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works. In the view you can resolve the storage provider, and then use that to get the public URL

```
@{
    var storageProvider = WorkContext.Resolve<IStorageProvider>();
}
<a class="logo" href="@Href("~/")">
    <img width="103" height="39" alt="" src="@Href(storageProvider.GetPublicUrl(settings.SiteLogoUrl))" >
</a>
```